# Rounded max value in dynamic array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, max

I am trying to get the highest value in an array. I wrote a code and it is working fine, but the result is a rounded value. 
I would like to se 99,98 instead of 100.

Can you help me with this?

```
     Dim aArray() As Double
        ReDim aArray(0 To 1) As Double


        For Each Row_cell In Range("A1:A100")
                   If Row_cell.Value = "Admin" Then
                       TargetRow = Row_cell.Row                                   
                   End If
        Next Row_cell

    For Each Column_Cell In range("b1:x1")
           If Column_Cell.Value = country_name Then
                  TargetCol = Column_Cell.Column  
                      If (IsNumeric(Cells(TargetRow, TargetCol)) And Cells(TargetRow, TargetCol) <> 0) Then
                       aArray(UBound(aArray)) = Cells(TargetRow, TargetCol).Value
                       ReDim Preserve aArray(0 To UBound(aArray) + 1)
                       End If
             End If
 Next Column_Cell

            maximum_value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(aArray)
            high_sheet.Cells(j, i) = maximum_value
            Erase aArray
            ReDim aArray(0 To 1) As Double
```

Comment: Have you tried ```CDbl(Cells(TargetRow, TargetCol).Value)```?

Comment: The `maximum_value` was declared as `Long`. With `Double` is working fine. Thank you for your help!